# Python ruamel.yaml code works in console but not in function (spyder)

Tags: python, spyder, ruamel.yaml

I am working in Spyder, Python version 3.9. I am running into an issue where a bit of code I have written in a function isn't working, but when running the code in the console, I get the desired outcome.

I am trying to write a function which takes items from a list and writes them to a YAML file. When the code is in a function, I will get an error. Below is a sample of what I would type in the console to try and run. I copied over the function that I had written in the code block into the console and tried running the below.

```
import ruaml.yaml
import pandas as pd

def getTable(tableDir):
    rawData = pd.read_csv(tableDir)
    tableData = pd.DataFrame(rawData)
    return tableData

def createYamlFile(tableDataLine, yamlFileName):
    yamlString = """

    """

    for i in range(0, len(tableDataLine), 1):
        yamlString = "{}{}\n".format(yamlString, tableDataLine[i]

    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
    yaml.preserve_quotes = True
    yamlContent = ruamel.yaml.safe_load(yamlString)

    with open(yamlFileName, 'w') as file:
        yaml.dump(yamlContent, file)

table = getTable(tableDir)
createYamlFile(table.iloc[0])
```

The desired outcome would look something like the following:

```
---
#0: Test0
1: Test1
2: Test2
#3: Test3
4: Test4
```

However, when I run the first code block in the console as-is, I get a `ComposerError: expected a single document in the stream`.

When I run the exact same code in the console, outside of the function though e.g.

```
table = getTable(tableDir)

yamlString = """

"""

for i in range(0, len(table.iloc[0]), 1):
    yamlString = "{}{}\n".format(yamlString, table.iloc[0][i])

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
yamlContent = ruamel.yaml.safe_load(yamlString)

with open(yamlFileName, 'w') as file:
    yaml.dump(yamlContent, file)
```

I am able to create my file just fine. The comments don't show up but this is a secondary problem to me. What is happening? How come the exact same code in the console works when it's not in a function?

Answer (score 0):

When you run this code:

```py
yaml_str = """\

"""

def fun():
    yaml_str = """

    """
    return yaml_str

print(repr(yaml_str))
print(repr(fun()))
```

it gives:

```
'\n'
'\n\n    '
```

So your console and your program don't start with the same string. Since your
code `"{}{}\n".format(yamlString, tableDataLine[i]` essentially concatenates the table
data a line at a time to that string, the first line gets indented, which is likely to cause an error.

If you want to specify YAML input code within a function (or any other indented environment) use either:
`yaml_str = "\n"` or if you need readable multiline input use `textwrap.dedent`:

```py
from textwrap import dedent

def fun():
    yaml_str = dedent("""\

    """)
    return yaml_str

print(repr(fun()))
```

which gives:

```
'\n'
```

I always use a backslash escape after the starting triple quotes to get rid of the leading newline.
You can also have multeline strings within a function that continue in the first column, but I find that unreadable.

---

A far bigger problem is you mising the old API ( `ruamel.yaml.safe_load()`) the new API (yaml = `ruamel.yaml.YAML()).
That will give problems and you should not be using the old API for *any new code*
(if possible notify the place where you got this broken code example from). Instead do use:

```py
import ruamel.yaml
from textwrap import dedent

def createYamlFile(tableDataLine, yamlFileName):
    yamlString = """

    """

    for i in range(0, len(tableDataLine), 1):
        yamlString = "{}{}\n".format(yamlString, tableDataLine[i])  # < closing parenthesis missing in non-console example

    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
    yaml.preserve_quotes = True
    yamlContent = yaml.load(yamlString)  # the default YAML() instance returns a subclass of the SafeLoader

    with open(yamlFileName, 'wb') as file:  # ruamel.yaml defaults to UTF-8, so use a binary file
        yaml.dump(yamlContent, file)
```